# Downloading from website with Request/Intent

Tags: java, android, jsoup, android-intentservice, webintents

I am making an app that will connect to a website and download an mp3 file.

Can you use intents along with a `HttpUrlConnection/jsoup` request (or is another way to accomplish this?) I am planning on using Jsoup to connect to [this site](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/), pass the url parameter, and somehow initiate the download (not sure how to acquire necessary url). I'm not sure how to implement this. I'd like to avoid using a webview to accomplish this, though that would be easy.

Comment: you can use download manager request

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira sorry can you elaborate alittle

Comment: you can read the doc at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html

Comment: you cannot do that, it requires user action to continue download. instead, open the url in webview

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira hmm is there no other way to access the download url without using a webview?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to download an mp3 file with a URL from the web, you could use the built-in download manager of android.

See #3 answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/1033546)

It's easy to implement and works well.

Comment: how would I programmatically initiate the download (" press" download button and get url)?